# Can not resolve symbol AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests in intellij

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, testng, spring-test

I am experiencing very strange problem in using **testng** in my project. I have created project with following dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.13.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I have written one class which extends `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`

```
import com.digicert.daas.reporting.listeners.ReportListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;


@Listeners(value = {ReportListener.class})
public  class ApplicationTestcaseReportListener extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{


}
```

When I import this maven project in my eclipse it works fine. But same project when I import in intellij it gives following error

**Can not resolve symbol AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests**

I tried to do rebuild project in intellij,but its not helping. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to specify a fixed version for your `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency?

Comment: @Nikem yes,that also didnt help.

Comment: Have you tried Project -> Maven -> Reimport?

Comment: Yes,tries that also.Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not missing this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Tried adding that.Problem remains.